# Flutter 'InAppWebview Error Origin is not allowed' when returning customscheme response with onLoadResourceWithCustomScheme on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-inappwebview

I have an application which display in an InAppWebView a local website. To do this, I instantiate a server (similar to InAppLocalhostServer) with as document root a directory in the app local repository, which contains the local website with an index.html as entry. The website loading works perfectly when I launch the webview with http://localhost:8080 as initial URL.
This website needs to load and read a encrypted JSON file which is stored on another repository on my local storage.
To do this, it use a fetch request which I need to intercept on my Flutter side to decrypt and return the JSON file.

So on the JS-side, it does something like this :

```
const response = await fetch(`mycustomscheme://folder/page.json`);
const data = await response.json();
```

And on the Flutter-side, for iOS, I intercept the request with onLoadResourceWithCustomScheme, I load the file (I checked on debug mode, it is ok) but the WebView doesn't load it. When I inspect the WebView using Safari, I have this error on the fetch request: `Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 0`

```
InAppWebViewSettings settings = InAppWebViewSettings(
    javaScriptEnabled: true,
    allowFileAccessFromFileURLs: true,
    allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs: true,
    resourceCustomSchemes: ["mycustomscheme"],
  );
InAppWebView(
          key: webViewKey,
          initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse("http://localhost:8080/index.html")),
          initialSettings: settings,
          ...,
          onLoadResourceWithCustomScheme: (controller, resource) async {
            if (resource.url.scheme == "mycustomscheme") {
              File file = await FileUtils().getFileFromLocalStorage(resource.url.toString().replaceAll("mycustomscheme://", "/"));
              Uint8List data = file.readAsBytesSync();
              CustomSchemeResponse response = CustomSchemeResponse(
                  contentType: lookupMimeType(file.path)!,
                  data: data
              );
              return response;
            }
          },
```

I added these lines to my Info.plist but it didn't change anything:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Is there something I forget or do wrong? I don't have the problem on Android as I can use the `shouldInterceptRequest` method which works correctly, but this method isn't available for iOS so `onLoadResourceWithCustomScheme` method seems to be the one to use. I tried with `shouldInterceptFetchRequest` also but we can only have control on the request, not the response.